# Cisco Switch login

Tags: cisco, switch

I have a switch as connected to the stack.  I got it off the internet so now I need to login to this switch.  I connected it to my laptop by the console cable and it did not let me to login with my adm user and password.  The company I work with has a contract with RSM and I can not get in unless they are going to use their username and password. What should i do  to login to the switch was in stack without contacting RSM?

Answer (score 5):

You will have to perform a password recovery.  You can find the procedure on Cisco's website, or follow [this link](https://community.cisco.com/t5/networking-knowledge-base/password-recovery/ta-p/3123097)